how to join (not nest) for loops with different indeces in python?
I have two for loops:
fig,axs = plt.subplots(11,11)
for i in range(11):
  for j in range(11):
    axs[i,j].plots[]
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('.png')

for label in sections['ab0']:
  print(label)
  print(plots[label])

plots is a dictionary of figures (value) each with a unique label (key):
{'90.0_30.0_40.0': <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>,
 '0.0_0.0_90.0': <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>,
 '90.0_100.0_30.0': <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>,
 ..}

sections is a dictionary of lists of labels (values) :
{'ab0': ['0.0_0.0_0.0', '0.0_0.0_10.0', '0.0_0.0_20.0',..],
 'ab10': ['0.0_10.0_0.0', '0.0_10.0_10.0', '0.0_10.0_20.0',..],
 'ab20': ['0.0_20.0_0.0', '0.0_20.0_10.0', '0.0_20.0_20.0',..],
 ..}

I need to substitute the 'plots[ ]' of the first nested-forloops, for the 'plots[label]' of the second for loop, without messing with their indices.
I honestly don't know how to do this, or how to achieve the same result by an alternate route.

I'm not sure I understand the problem. Could you make a [mre] with self-contained code and exact desired input and output?

I think I just got it and I have a solution, but I want to confirm before I post it.

Are there 121 labels in sections['ab0'] and are you trying to assign the figures from plots to the figure in the order they are in sections['ab0']?
